# Can I see a list of jobs that cron runs @reboot?

Tags: cron, reboot

In /var/log/cron.log I noticed that CRON runs "@reboot jobs" right after I start my computer.

Is there a way for me to see the list of the jobs CRON triggers then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's an easy way to see all configured `cron` jobs.

First, check the global crontab file under `/etc/crontab` for anything containing `@reboot`.

```
grep '^\s*@reboot' /etc/crontab
```

As `root`, you can check the `crontab` of your users like this:

```
crontab -u $user -l | grep '^\s*@reboot'
```

Comment: `grep '^\s*@reboot'` for both should be precise.

Comment: @rexkogitans thanks for the headsup! Edited the answer.

Comment: For the first command I get no output, and for the second command I get "sudo: unknown user -l; sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin" I don't know the meaning  about the policy plugin. Going back to the first command, would this mean that although @reboot runs, there are no jobs to trigger?

Comment: You need to replace `$user` with the name of a user on your system.

Answer (score 1):

You can run

```
sudo sh -c 'cat /etc/crontab \
  /etc/cron.d/* \
  /var/spool/cron/crontabs/*'
```

to see all cron jobs.

Filter it with

```
sudo sh -c 'cat /etc/crontab \
  /etc/cron.d/* \
  /var/spool/cron/crontabs/*' | grep '^\s*@reboot'
```

(as noted by @rexkogitans)